# Setting distance of discrete x axis ticks / grid lines relative to line breaks in x labels

Tags: r, ggplot2

## How can I control the height of the grid in ggplot?

[image]

### Code to reproduce:

Here is the code to reproduce the 2 figures below

```r
data <- data.frame(Schools = c(
  paste("some random school name", 1:5),
  paste("school name", LETTERS[1:5])
), Students = 121:125)

data$Schools <- factor(x = data$Schools, levels = sample(data$Schools))

ggplot(data = data, mapping = aes(x = Students, y = Schools)) +
  geom_point(show.legend = T, alpha = 0.7) +
  theme_bw()

data1 <- data.frame(Schools = c(
  paste("some random\nschool name", 1:5),
  paste("school name", LETTERS[1:5])
), Students = 121:125)

data1$Schools <- factor(x = data1$Schools, levels = sample(data1$Schools))

ggplot(data = data1, mapping = aes(x = Students, y = Schools)) +
  geom_point(show.legend = T, alpha = 0.7) +
  theme_bw()
```

So, for the figure on the right side, I would like the grid height to be shorter for the labels written in 1 line.

Comment: So you want 100 units on the y-axis to be 1 cm but a different set of 100 units on the y-axis to be 3 cm? How do you imagine this looks like?

Comment: Yes, I understand how this plot would look like. But, this is not exactly the same plot I want to make. For the plot I want to make, it will fit there. This is just an example.

Comment: But we don't understand what this plot would look like. Do you want some kind of nonlinear transformation that makes the first 100 units 1 cm and the next 100 units to be 3 cm? You can set the absolute dimensions of a plot panel in a gtable object, but I don't see how that would help the 1cm-3cm discrepancy.

Comment: To be specific, I have some labels on the y-axis, which have `nchar()` over 100, and I want to break them in multiple lines. Now, when I plot it,  the grids are equally spaced.

I would not like to have more space for labels which fit in just 1 line.

Comment: I updated the figure. So, for the figure on the right side, I would like the grid height to be shorter for the labels written in 1 line.

Comment: Please update your question (put your comment into the question). the last comment makes your question so much clearer.

Comment: I've changed the title - please review and check if this represents better what you wanted to ask.